# Java/Android/Eclipse: IllegalArgumentException: already added

Tags: java, android, eclipse, illegalargumentexception

I have a Java project "*EDNA*" in my Eclipse environment that uses libraries called *libosm* and *osmnavigation*.

[image]

I export "*EDNA*" containing *libosm* and *osmnavigation* into a jar. The EDNA.jar gets imported in my Android 2.2 project "*Tableted*" (copied to libs folder). *libosm* and *osmnavigation* get added automatically:

[image]

*Tableted* has nothing set in "Java Build Path -> Projects". "Java Build Path -> Libraries" looks like this:

[image]

When I hit Debug the following error occurs:

```
[2012-11-13 09:53:20 - Tableted] Dx bad class file magic (cafebabe) or version (0033.0000)
...while parsing de/hk/econnect/math/CHull.class
...while processing de/hk/econnect/math/CHull.class
[2012-11-13 09:53:20 - Tableted] Dx 
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added:     Lcom/bretth/osmosis/core/xml/v0_5/XmlDownloader;
at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:486)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:455)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$400(Main.java:67)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:394)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:245)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:131)
at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:109)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:418)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:329)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:206)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.DexWrapper.run(DexWrapper.java:180)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.BuildHelper.executeDx(BuildHelper.java:703)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.build.builders.PostCompilerBuilder.build(PostCompilerBuilder.java:577)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager$2.run(BuildManager.java:728)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:199)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.basicBuild(BuildManager.java:321)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.build(BuildManager.java:396)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2344)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:124)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.ProjectHelper.doFullIncrementalDebugBuild(ProjectHelper.java:1000)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.launch.LaunchConfigDelegate.launch(LaunchConfigDelegate.java:147)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:937)
at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1141)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
[2012-11-13 09:53:20 - Tableted] Dx 10 warnings
[2012-11-13 09:53:20 - Tableted] Dx 1 error; aborting
[2012-11-13 09:53:20 - Tableted] Conversion to Dalvik format failed with error 1
```

---

Instead of adding the jar I also tried to reference the project. But this leads to the same error.

Comment: What do you mean "libosm and osmnavigation get added automatically"? I don't think Android SDK/ADT has this kind of function that automatically expose transitive dependencies into libs/ folder. It must be added by someone. The simplest solution is to remove libosm and osmnavigation from libs, if they are runtime only dependencies to you application project, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are they added and marked under the "Order & Export" tab?
Else try this, it's a general issue, in my oppinion red., that it doesn't get them export correctly.

Comment: Yes, they are checked under "Java Build Path -> Order and Export" als the last entries in the list.

Comment: Move it up, positioning matters.

Comment: I moved libosm and osmnavigation on top of the list, it didn't make a difference.

Comment: And your EDNA ?, screenshot it pls